# Convert Java Date into another Time as Date format

Tags: java, timezone, date-conversion

I want to convert date into "indies time".  Specifically: "Asia/Calcutta".

Code:

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Date date=new Date();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));

String dateString=simpleDateFormat.format(date);

System.out.println("Currect Date : " + dateString);
// This is returning a string and I want a date.

System.out.println("Wrong Output : "+simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString)); 
//This returns a Date but has incorrect result.
```

Here is the output of the above code:

```
Correct Date : 2013-04-15 15:40:04
Wrong Output : Mon Apr 15 03:10:04 MST 2013
```

I want the DATE, not the string, but when I retrieve the date, the time is `3:10`, and when I get the string, I get `15:40:04`.  Why are these not the same?

Comment: Just to add to others... a Date object just represents a point in time and contains **no** TZ knowledge even though you may have created it using a SimpleDateFormat object that **is** aware of TZ. Whenever you convert a date to its string representation, a TZ must be used in order to know how it should be shown. Since a Date doesn't know the TZ, when you call `date.toString()` as you did implicitly, it has no choice other than to assume you mean the **default** TZ. You must format it using your SDF that is aware of TZ instead of relying on the `toString()` method of Date.

Answer (score 2):

parse() parses the date text and constructs the Date object which is a long value. The parse() javadoc says

```
The TimeZone value may be overwritten, depending on the given pattern and 
the time zone value in text. Any TimeZone value that has previously been 
set by a call to setTimeZone may need to be restored for further operations.
```

Your parse Date object is printed by calling the toString() on Date which has printed it in the MST timezone. If you convert it from MST to IST then you will get the timestamp which you are expecting. So, your output is correct. All you need to do is format and print your long Date value using the correct timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Parse will return a DateObject, so calling :

```
System.out.println("Wrong Output : "+simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString));
```

is somewhat similar to :

```
Date d1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
System.out.println("Wrong Output : "+d1.toString());
```

Remember parsing a date is just to parse a String to generate a date object, if you want to display it in a certain format, use that date object and call sdf.format on it.
e.g.

```
 String dateStringOut=simpleDateFormat.format(d1);
 System.out.println("Output : "+dateStringOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Date` does not contain any formatting. It is simply a `Date`. You can therefore not convert your `Date` object between different output formats. Once you have the date, there's no need trying to convert it into a different format. How to format it is decided when you convert it to a `String` with your `SimpleDateFormat`. So once you have parsed your `Date`, just keep it around until you need to format it for output.

Comment: When date store into database i wont to store in to indien time zone.

Comment: If `dateString` already produces the correct format, then what is the problem?

Comment: when i parse it return String but then that String wont to conver into Date in indian time.

Answer (score 0):

Use static function getDateTimeInstance(int dateStyle,int timeStyle) of DateFormat class.
See DateFormat Class for further details. It may help you.