# Converting String in ISO8601 T-Z format to Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

Possible Solution:[Convert Java Date into another Time as Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012614/convert-java-date-into-another-time-as-date-format)

I went through it but does not get my answer.

I have a string "**2013-07-17T03:58:00.000Z**" and I want to convert it into date of the same form which we get while making a new Date().Date d=new Date();

The time should be in IST Zone - Asia/Kolkata

Thus the date for the string above should be

Wed Jul 17 12:05:16 IST 2013    //Whatever Time as per Indian Standard GMT+0530

```
String s="2013-07-17T03:58:00.000Z";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); 
TimeZone tx=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
formatter.setTimeZone(tx);
d= (Date)formatter.parse(s);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use calendar for timezones.

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
sdf.setCalendar(cal);
cal.setTime(sdf.parse("2013-07-17T03:58:00.000Z"));
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

For this however I'd recommend [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net/) as it has better functions for this situation. For JodaTime you can do something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime("2013-07-17T03:58:00.000Z");
Date date = dt.toDate();
```

Comment: Does it retun me a Date Object?

Comment: Edited so last line is returning it to date. However note that Date has no timezone.

Comment: But joda Time jar file is heavy.And including it just for converting date once make sense?

Comment: This is why I also included something that uses calendar, in case you didn't want to use Joda Time?

Comment: After a long search, I found this is the only working solution. Thanks @MarkM

Answer (score 4):

A Date doesn't have any time zone. If you want to know what the string representation of the date is in the indian time zone, then use another SimpleDateFormat, with its timezone set to Indian Standard, and format the date with this new SimpleDateFormat.

EDIT: code sample:

```
String s = "2013-07-17T03:58:00.000Z";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
Date d = formatter.parse(s);

System.out.println("Formatted Date in current time zone = " + formatter.format(d));

TimeZone tx=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
formatter.setTimeZone(tx);
System.out.println("Formatted date in IST = " + formatter.format(d));
```

Output (current time zone is Paris - GMT+2):

```
Formatted Date in current time zone = 2013-07-17T05:58:00.000+02
Formatted date in IST = 2013-07-17T09:28:00.000+05
```

Comment: Hii..I have edited my code..But Its saying unable to parse the string.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat string should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` otherwise got _java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'_

Comment: @VijayC That depends on your Java version. `Z` means offset zero or “Zulu time zone”, so you should prefer to make sure you parse it as such.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I should like to provide the modern answer. And give you a suggestion: rather than reproducing what `Date.toString()` would have given you, better to use the built-in format for users in the relevant locale:

```
    String isoString = "2013-07-17T03:58:00.000Z";
    String humanReadable = Instant.parse(isoString)
            .atZone(userTimeZone)
            .format(localizedFormatter);
    System.out.println(humanReadable);
```

On my computer this prints

```
17 July 2013 at 09.28.00 IST
```

My snippet uses a couple of constants

```
private static final ZoneId userTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
private static final DateTimeFormatter localizedFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
        .withLocale(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
```

The `withLocale` call is redundant when we just pass the default format locale. I put it in so you have a place to provide an explicit locale, should your users require a different one. It also has the nice advantage of making explicit that the result depends on locale, in case someone reading your code didn’t think of that.

I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with than the outdated `Date`, `TimeZone` and the notoriously troublesome `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Your string conforms to the ISO 8601 standard, a format that the modern classes parse as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

### Same format as Date gave you

Of course you can have the same format as the old-fashioned `Date` would have given you if you so require. Just substitute the formatter above with this one:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter asUtilDateFormatter 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
```

Now we get:

```
Wed Jul 17 09:28:00 IST 2013
```

### Link to tutorial

Read more about using `java.time` in [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and/or find other resources out there.