# convert date from one format to another in java

Tags: java, date

I need to convert a date from one format to another in java. Here I am not converting the date from one format to another format. First I have to retrieve from XMLGregorianCalendar  and then I have to convert it to yyyyDDDHHmmssSSS which should be same as the below explained by hard coding.

Problem:

I have hard code a value in string and then I try to convert to date and then to back to original value(yyyyDDDHHmmssSSS) format, I am getting the expected value as below.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDDHHmmssSSS");
String t  ="20160690600530";
Date dateq = sdf1.parse(t);
System.out.println("After converting"+   dateq );
System.out.println("normalTest--->"+sdf1.format(dateq));
```

Output: (Expected one)

```
Wed Mar 09 06:00:53 EST 2016  
sss-->2016069010053000
```

Same way I am trying to convert a value from the XMLGregorianCalendar to yyyyDDDHHmmssSSS, but I am getting a different value from the above.

```
Pojo ddd = new Pojo();
XMLGregorianCalendar  gregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2016-03-09T06:00:53.0Z");
ddd.setMemberEffectiveTimestamp(gregorianCalendar);
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDDHHmmssSSS");
Date date1 = ddd.getMemberEffectiveTimestamp().toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
System.out.println("date1--->"+date1);
System.out.println("sss-->"+ sdf1.format(date1));
```

Output:

```
date1--->Wed Mar 09 01:00:53 EST 2016
sss-->2016069010053000
```

I need the "2016-03-09T06:00:53.0Z" to convert to 2016069010053000 value.
I am not sure how to achieve it.

Comment: Do you need this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692863/converting-string-in-t-z-format-to-date

Comment: Are you in `GMT+5` timezone? If you need `Z` timezone I suggest you `setTimeZone` to GMT.

Comment: @bharanthi Did you intend to stay entirely with UTC as the time zone for each value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Avoid old date-item classes

You are using outmoded old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. They have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built-in. A vast improvement!

In java.time, an `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

Your input string complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating string representations of their date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern. The `Instant` class can directly parse such a string.

```
String input = "2016-03-09T06:00:53.0Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse ( input );
```

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is only intended as a basic building block. So for generating formatted strings we must convert to an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. You apparently want the same time zone of UTC, so we specify the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

We define a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to use your pattern. The reader should note the desired pattern uses the uppercase-D `DDD` pattern which means day-of-year (a count between 1 and 365/366).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyyDDDHHmmssSSS" );
String output = odt.format ( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " = instant: " + instant + " = odt: " + odt + " = output: " + output );
```

When run.

> input: 2016-03-09T06:00:53.0Z = instant: 2016-03-09T06:00:53Z = odt: 2016-03-09T06:00:53Z = output: 2016069060053000

Caution: I strongly **recommend against generating such strings lacking any [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)** or time zone information. That is as unwise as transmitting a currency amount without noting *which* currency (USD, CAD, MXN, etc.).

Such serializations of date-time values to strings should stick to the sensible and intuitive formats defined by ISO 8601 whenever possible.