# ParseException while parsing date from String to date Object

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing, parseexception

I'm getting a `ParseException` while parsing a date from `String` to `Date` object. The date string also contains a timezone. I'm using this code:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
System.out.print(sdf.parse("2018-01-16T00:07:00.000+05:30"));
```

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-01-16T00:07:00.000+05:30"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

Comment: what about the TO that exists between the date string??? you need to cater it too.

Comment: Well ... Does the parsed string follow the same format as the format specifier?

Comment: This exception happened because you are not matching the date you want to parse.

Comment: Try the answers provided in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692863/converting-string-in-t-z-format-to-date

Comment: I recommend that in 2018 you stay away from the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @srp321, the answers found in the question you link to use `SimpleDateFormat` too, I recommend you avoid that and use `java.time` instead. See the modern and easy solution in [the answer by Laurent B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48518250/5772882).

Comment: @OleV.V. i wasn't sure if OP was using java 8, so i suggested as per the usage he already had implemented, and thanks for recommending, in scenarios when i have Java 8 available, i use java.time utilities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format you use in `SimpleDateFormat` must match the input `String`.

Your input is `2018-01-16T00:07:00.000+05:30`, which is [ISO8601 compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

- year-month-day (`2018-01-16`)
- followed by the letter `T`
- followed by hour:minutes:seconds.milliseconds (`00:07:00.000`)
- followed by the [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (`+05:30`)

*Note: the offset `+05:30` is **not** a timezone. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) to know the difference.*

Anyway, the pattern you're using (`"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"`) doesn't match the input string:

- it's missing the `T` between date and time
- it's missing the milliseconds
- there's a space before the offset
- the correct letter to parse offsets is `X` (although I think that `z` might work, depending on the JVM version you're using; in my tests, it didn't)

So your code should be:

```
// use "XXX" to parse the whole offset (only one "X" will parse just `+05`, missing the `:30` part)
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date d = sdf.parse("2018-01-16T00:07:00.000+05:30");
```

But it's much better to use the new Java 8 classes, if they're available to you:

```
// parse ISO8601 compliant string directly
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-01-16T00:07:00.000+05:30");
```

If you still need to use a `java.util.Date` object, it's easy to convert:

```
// convert to java.util.Date
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Comment: Very well explained answer, thanks. Agree to use the Java 8 classes. New? Only four years old. :-) Available in Java 6 and 7 too through the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Answer (score 1):

Your are using an ISO 8601 date.

Using SimpleDateFormat :

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSSX");
System.out.print(sdf.parse("2018-01-16T00:07:00.000+05:30"));
```

Alertnatively, you can use the build in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) parsing provided :

**Using joda time** [Instant](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html):

```
Instant.parse("2018-01-16T00:07:00.000+05:30")
```

**JAVA 8 :** (prefered see comment below)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

```
    System.out.println(java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(s));
```

Comment: Instant.parse("2018-01-16T00:07:00.000+05:30") doesn't work, it throws java.time.format.DateTimeParseException

Comment: @Rahul edited as it worked with joda but java 8 Instant does not support timezones, you have to use OffsetDateTime

Comment: It’s preferred to use the Java 8 solution. Joda-Time is in maintenance mode, and `SimpleDateFormat` long outdated and notoriously troublesome. If using Java 6 or 7, consider adding [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project so you can use the Java 8 solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
          System.out.print(sdf.parse("2018-01-16 0:07:00 +0530"));
```

You are trying to parse z which stands for General time zone eg GMT IST etc but you need Z zone-offset like +0530 for India.Also remove the `OT` between the string. Your date format should match with the pattern.
Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: RFC 822  is the ARPA Internet Text Messages specification. The format OP is using is correct according to the ISO 8601

Comment: @LaurentB see my edit..z  time-zone name  zone-name Pacific Standard Time; PST while  Z  zone-offset    offset-Z  +0000; -0800; -08:00; is what I am trying to say..which is just another approach to solve the problem